# how to get the project specific jira issues using jira rest api in .net?

Tags: c#, json, api, rest

I have a requirement where i need to get all the issues for a particular project in jira so for this i have created a console application which has rest client class using which I make a GET request call and for testing purpose rest api url is

"https://jira.atlassian.com/rest/api/latest/issue/JRA-9"

using this url i make  a HttpWebRequest and get the response back in json formated string. Now this json string contain all the issue specific information but my actual requrement is to get all the project specific issues.

I tried to find out if i get any project specifc URL for testing purpose from where i get json reply back and I found `http://kelpie9:8081/rest/api/2/search?jql=project=QA+order+by+duedate&fields=id,key` but for this i get the "The remote name could not be resolved: 'kelpie9'" error.

Could you please help me in this?
`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

JIRA's REST API does not appear to currently support any `project`-based queries separate from their [`search` API](https://developer.atlassian.com/display/JIRADEV/JIRA+REST+API+Example+-+Query+issues).

You can specify a specific project in the search by using the JQL. Given that you know a project (e.g., "JRA" in "JRA-9"), then you can quickly search through all of its issues:

Working result: [`https://jira.atlassian.com/rest/api/latest/search?jql=project=JRA`](https://jira.atlassian.com/rest/api/latest/search?jql=project=JRA)

One important note is that the results return actual total versus what is actually returned:

```
"startAt":0,"maxResults":50,"total":30177
```

You can add query string variables to the request to get more (or less) results. You can also control the fields related to issues to retrieve as well:  [`https://jira.atlassian.com/rest/api/latest/search?jql=project=JRA&startAt=75&maxResults=75`](https://jira.atlassian.com/rest/api/latest/search?jql=project=JRA&startAt=75&maxResults=75) (slower the more you request, and probably not nice to hit their public servers with big numbers).

You can even `POST` a JSON object that represents the query (slightly tweaked from the linked [`search`](https://developer.atlassian.com/display/JIRADEV/JIRA+REST+API+Example+-+Query+issues) docs):

```
{"jql":"project = JRA","startAt":75,"maxResults":75,"fields":["id","key"]}
```

Of interest, and as part of the JQL, you can sort the results by any field. Just add " order by id" to the project name, as-in "jql=JRA+order+by+id" in the querystring or `"jql": "project = JRA order by id"` in the `POST`ed JSON body.

---

Note: Above is the actual answer to the real question. However, the literal question is the cause of the `The remote name could not be resolved: 'kelpie9' error.

Their documentation shows `kelpie9` as an example server name that they are testing on internally, running on port `8081`. Your computer is not aware of a server/machine named `kelpie9`, as it does not publicly exist.  Replace `kelpie9` with whatever your JIRA server's hostname is internally and `8081` with whatever port it is using (or remove it if you do not see one when you view JIRA on your intranet site, which means port 80 for http and port 443 for https).  For example, many companies run it a `"https://jira/"`. You would replace the example link with `https://jira/rest/api/2/search?jql=project=QA+order+by+duedate&fields=id,key`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer it was very useful. I have one question, i tried with " https://jira.atlassian.com/rest/api/latest/search?jql=project=JRA&startAt=75&maxResults=75 " and it is working fine but when i tried with our internal jira "http://jira2.ms.com/jira/issues/#?jql=project+%3D+%22Core+Processing+Distributed+Support%22" then the httpWebRequest was asking me for the user credentials and provided that and then after i got the reponse but it is html source insted of json. I doubt that the URL that i am using is not JIRA REST API URL. Do you have any idea what went wrong?

Comment: can anybody answer this my query above?

Comment: As you thought, you are querying your internal site, and not the JIRA REST API. I would expect that you should query http://jira2.ms.com/jira/rest/api/latest/search?jql=project=Core+Processing+Distributed+Support . As for the authorization, you can supply the [appropriate headers](https://developer.atlassian.com/display/JIRADEV/JIRA+REST+API+Example+-+Basic+Authentication) in the HTTP request.

Comment: now i have done with getting all the jira issues now i want to get the jira timesheet using reat api. I tried this rest api url "https://jira.atlassian.com/rest/timesheet-gadget/1.0/raw-timesheet.json" but it didint worked. could you please let me know waht is wrong?

Comment: Never used it, sorry.